# Conflict in Maven Dependencies not getting resolved

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, google-cloud-speech

I am working with Google cloud APIs for Google Speech and Google Natural Language Processing. The version i am using for both is as follows:

> google-cloud-speech: 0.13.0-alpha
>
> google-cloud-language: 0.9.4-alpha

And both of them uses the google-gax api as an internal dependency. While speech api using the gax version 0.10.0, the language api uses the 0.1.4.
In the pom, i have the depedency scope as provided. So for the reason, i am providing the jars in the lib folder of the server.

But the issues is with the gax api. The problem is:

> When i provide the gax version 0.10.0, the speech api works but language api does not work.
>
> If the gax version 0.1.4 is provided, then language api works but the speech apis doesn't works.
>
> And if both the version are provided, then only speech api works.

Any suggestions to resolve the issue? I have tried everything viz cleaning the project, updating the maven, re-deploy the project, delete all maven dependecy and rebuild. But did not get the problem resolved.

Comment: There is no way - find compatible versions of the libraries. You could maybe write a "shim" to make language work with gax 0.10.0. (I lie, custom classloaders or OSGI would work - but that's beyond the scope of this question methinks).

Comment: This is the price you pay for using alpha versions. It looks very much to me like the two libraries are intended to be used at the _same_ version (for example `0.8.0`.

Comment: Besides using custom classloaders or osgi and not changing the versions you are using: Extract the jar's, decompile, move types to corresponding packages (like gax.v0_10_0 and gax.v_0_1_4) , reimport types, repackage. I would not recommend it, but if you really really have to. We did that once, it worked, it was a lot of pain, but it worked,... (and another thing: in maven, you can exclude transitive dependencies, that might be helpful one day)

Comment: @slowy..I already tried similar kind of painfull work, but it did not worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the google-cloud-language worked well. Now updated the language version to

> google-cloud-language-0.13.0-alpha

and everything worked smoothly. The reason being this version uses the gax-0.10.0 and thus resolving the conflicts.